# How to display information dynamically in modal popup bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I would like to display a modal popup with `bootstrap`.This modal should display information which should be placed dynamically. What I want is to display a name in *nome articolo* ecc ecc .Here is what I've done so far.

```
    <span class="btn-group">
    <a href="#responsive" role="button" class="btn btn-small" data-toggle="modal" data-id="prova"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
</span>


                <!-- Modal Definitions (tabbed over for <pre>) -->
<div id="responsive" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Inserisci Articolo</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12">
        <p>Codice Barre  <input type="text" class="span12" name="codiceBarre" id="codiceBarre" /></p>
        <p>Nome Articolo <input type="text" class="span12" /></p>
        <p>Quantit&agrave;  <input type="text" class="span12" /></p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Chiudi</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For show modal use of course: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Init:

```
$('#responsive').modal(options)
```

If you want to append content of this div dynamically, just append content into div

```
$('#responsive').append(content) or $('#responsive').html( content )
```

Then display modal

```
$('#responsive').modal('show')
```

Comment: Ok, i have insert it in tag a data-id="prova", but how i get it from modal?

Comment: What kind of data you want to pass into modal ? 
E.g if you have element in modal: <span id="example"></span>, and you want to insert there a text you sould do something like:
#('#example').html( "some text" );